# I need a tip on how to get my insertion code to work in php and mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I am having problems updating and inserting data into my database. I have debugged most of the program so I know for sure that the problem is the line of code for updating and the line of code for inserting data. I am very confused because their are other functions that use the same code and all the variables I used in each function were declared locally in the function so I know they are not conflicting. the code at the top that says 
 is all the database code to open the line of communication with the database and php. That code works I've already tested it in other programs. I can still pull data with the SELECT code from the database and I've checked and double checked if the names match up with the table. This code is part of some ajax code so it will update in real time but the post I use with the javascript transfers the data just fine to the php file. So I have no idea what I'm doing wrong or if there is just something wrong with the server. If anyone as any ideas please let me know. Also the purpose of this code is to make it so that users can like, favorite, and give a rating out of 5 stars to the content they are viewing on my site.

This is the code:

```
<?php include "base.php";?>
</head>
<?php
$rateMe = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rating WHERE Username = '".$_SESSION['Username']."' AND Title = '".$_POST['myTitle']."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($rateMe) == 0)
{
    $registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO rating (Username, Author, Star, Like, Favorite, Title) VALUES('".$_SESSION['Username']."','".$_POST['myAuthor']."','".$_POST['myrating']."','".$_POST['myLike']."', '".$_POST['myFavorite']."', '".$_POST['myTitle']."')");
}else
{
    $makeUpdate = mysql_query("UPDATE rating SET Star = '".$_POST['myrating']."' WHERE Username = '".$_SESSION['Username']."' AND Title = '".$_POST['myTitle']."'");
}
?>
```

and this is the table I'm trying to insert data into

table: rating

Username varchar(255)

Author varchar(255)

Star float

Like varchar(255)

Favorite varchar(255)

Title varchar(255)

Comment: OP, please try to echo the query then try to execute it using some MySQL client (phpMyAdmin for example).

Comment: have you echoed your sql query too see what it is passing or print `mysql_error`

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what your insert query will probably be like when you print it

```
INSERT INTO rating (Username, Author, Star, Like, Favorite, Title) VALUES('John','Jim','xx','xx', 'xx', 'xx')
```

The `like` keyword in the insert statement will probably throw an error like below

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'like) values('John'

Check your update if it's working

Comment: ok I did what you said and you were right thank you that helped alot. Solved all my current issues.

Answer (score 0):

As Markus intimated, your code is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  Further, the PHP manual strongly recommends using the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) extension, over the mysql extension.

I would suggest you take a moment to read through [this article](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) on PDO, prepared statements and the right way to INSERT/UPDATE data into your model.

Comment: I read the article and I thank you for it. I will update my sql so that doesn't happen. I appreciate it, still very fresh outta college and unfortunately they didn't cover that. You have advanced my sql knowledge.